# Estoy intentando convertir una columna object a datetime y solo con la parte de fecha (d/m/y) , sin la hora

Tags: python, pandas

Cuando utilizo la funcion datetime me devuelve formato (y/m/d H:M:S) y yo quisiera lograr solo (d/m/y).

Aplico la siguiente linea, pero me devuelve un object y no un datetime, aunque visualmente el formato es el deseado:

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Antes de hacer la conversión, ¿de qué tipo son los elementos de `df['Date']`?

Comment: Hola Jorge, gracias por tu respuesta. Son de tipo object

Comment: Pero objetos ¿de qué clase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para responder a la pregunta.

**Respuesta corta:**

- `strftime()` esta generado un `str` de python por lo que pandas lo cataloga como `object`.
- `[x.date() for x in pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])]` generara elementos del tipo `datetime`, pero al ser dtypes de python, pandas seguira indicando que los `dtypes` son `object`.

**Respuesta larga:**

Primero hay que entender a que hace referencia pandas cuando devuelve un `dtype` de `object`. Y es que, cuando devuelve este valor:

- ya sea que esta haciendo referencia a que tiene dtypes de pandas mixtos.
- O, a que tiene dtypes de python.

Recordando que, como pandas es una extension de numpy, hereda los dtypes de este. Por lo que pueden diferir algo de los de python. Un ejemplo de esto es que el `str` de python no es exactamente lo mismo que `StringDtype` de pandas.

En este caso, al momento de usar `strftime()` se esta generando un `str` de python, por lo que pandas lo asigna como `object`. Habiendo dicho esto, a pesar de ser `str`, aun puede servir para hacer algunas operaciones sencillas de fechas en caso de requerirlas.

Ahora que si se necesita que forzosamente todos los elementos sean `datetime`, hay de dos:

- Solo ejecutar `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` (notar que aqui el dtype si corresponde con uno de tiempo) y hacer las operaciones de fechas requeridas y luego convertirlo a str usando  `strftime()` para que sea mas amable visualmente.
- O, usar `[x.date() for x in pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])]`, que convertida los datos a nivel individual a datetime en el formato requerido, aunque, pandas lo seguira catalogando como `object` al ser un dtype de python.

En caso de querer profundizar en el tema de los dtypes de pandas, la liga al guia oficial es la siguiente:

- dtypes en general:
  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#basics-dtypes
- dtypes de texto:
  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#text-types

Espero que sea de ayuda.